# Vuetify : v-text-field input restore value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

It's a simple app with `v-text-field` for input. I want to enable user input for only numbers, if I try to type like `11a` and then press tab or click mouse out of input before I lost focus I see `11`, but then focus lost I see `11a`. I don't understand how last symbol restored and how fix it. What am I doing wrong?

````
  <div id="app">
    <h1>{{message}}</h1>

    <v-text-field @input.native="setOnlyNumber" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      message: 'Welcome to Vue!'
    };
  },
  methods: {
    setOnlyNumber(e) {
      e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(/\D+/, '');
    }
  }
};
</script>```

It is my example app on codepen
https://codepen.io/aleksandra973/pen/BamYdOO
````

Answer (score 1):

You can use `type="number"` in `<v-text-field>` element.

**Working Demo :**

```js
Vue.use(Vuetify);

var vm = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      message: 'Welcome to Vue!'
    };
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h1>{{message}}</h1>
  <v-text-field type="number" label="Number Input Field"/>
</div>
```

As per the comment by author, Adding below working code snippet which will accept both number and alphabets only.

```js
Vue.use(Vuetify);

var vm = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      message: 'Welcome to Vue!'
    };
  },
  methods: {
    validateInput(e) {
      let char = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode); // Get the character
      if(/^[0-9A-Za-z]+$/.test(char)) return true; // Match with regex 
      else e.preventDefault(); // If not match, don't add to input text
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h1>{{message}}</h1>
  <v-text-field type="text" label="Number Input Field" v-on:keypress="validateInput($event)"/>
</div>
```

Comment: It is ok for only number case, but if I want input with number and letters?

Comment: In that case you have to use `regex` which validate the input text on `keypress`.

Comment: @Alexandra I added working code snippet as per the requirement you mentioned here in the comment.

Comment: It will be work not in all cases(( For example command + V (ctrl + v) or paste by mouse

Comment: In that case you can use the same logic on focus out instead of keypress

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to make use of the Number type input of HTML5.

v-text-field can use this type with the following flag:

```
<v-text-field type='number' />
```

Alternatively, you could bind to the data and run a validation as follows:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <h1>{{message}}</h1>

    <v-text-field v-model='number' @change="validate" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      message: 'Welcome to Vue!',
      number: null,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    validate() {
      this.number = this.number.toString().replace(/\D+/, '');
    }
  }
};
</script>
```